# Custom Styling water and roads using HERE Android SDK

Tags: here-api

This seems pretty straightforward, but it isn't working.  I am able to custom style certain things using the Here SDK (such as airports.) But trying to change the color of something like water is not working.

ZoomRange range = new ZoomRange(0.0, 100.0);
scheme.setVariableValue(CustomizableVariables.Water.COLOR_0M, Color.BLACK, range);

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Solved...for those interested you have to set all the DISPLAYCLASS[X] colors for all the relevant water structures.

Comment: Two more comments on this: a) CustomizableVariables.Water.COLOR_0M is only applicable for oceans, the displayclasses you mentioned are correct for everything else. Not optimal, I have to admit. b) Zoomlevels in the HERE Mobile SDK range from 1.0 (globe view) to 20.0 (close to ground). It doesn't harm that you set 1 to 100, but I just wanted to mention it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Summary: 
Solved by setting all the `DISPLAYCLASS[X]` colors for all the relevant water structures.

Two comments:

1. `CustomizableVariables.Water.COLOR_0M` is only applicable for oceans, the displayclasses you mentioned are correct for everything else.
2. Zoomlevels in the HERE Mobile SDK range from 1.0 (globe view) to 20.0 (close to ground). It doesn't harm that you set 1 to 100, but for your note.